# Criar um Array PHP com valores de meses passados do ano Utilizando a API Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

Estou precisando criar um gráfico de relatórios do começo do ano até os dias de hoje. E a minha ideia é utilizar um gráfico de linha que a cada mês mostre o valor de um relatório definido por mim mesmo.

Exemplo: no mês de Janeiro eu vendi 50 produtos, e no mês de Fevereiro vendi 52 produtos, no gráfico aparecerá somente o mês de Janeiro, Fevereiro e o mês seguinte (mês atual, como exemplo).

Para pegar as datas estou utilizando a API Carbon [Aqui](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) e para pegar o valor dos dados de um mês a outro, estou usando um exemplo abaixo feito por mim mesmo:

```
$quantidadeMesPassado = Produto::where(['teste'=>$teste])
             ->whereBetween('updated_at',[$comecoMes, $fimDoMes])
             ->get()
             ->count();
```

A `$quantidadeMesPassado` pega o valor no banco de dados com uma condição, o `$comecoMesPassado` possui o começo do mês com o `Carbon` e o `$fimDoMes` possui o fim do mês como mostrado abaixo.

```
$comecoMes = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth();
$fimDoMes =  Carbon::now()->endOfMonth();
```

Porém estou com duvida para executar criar um `array` do `PHP` e passar todos os meses desde o começo do ano até agora (*hoje é julho, o array não deve possuir agosto e outros meses a frente*), de forma automática.

Abaixo há um exemplo que estou utilizando no meu código pra pegar o valor do mês.

```
$comecoJaneiro = new Carbon('first day of January');
$comecoFevereiro = new Carbon('first day of February');
$mes = $comecoJaneiro->month;
```

A princípio, penso que a `$quantidadeMesPassado` possa ser um `array` que possua os valores do `$comecoMes` e `$fimDoMes` de todos os meses anteriores do atual mês. Já a duvida é como saber quais são todos os meses anteriores. Para que `$comecoMes` e `$fimDoMes` seja o `array` que possua todos os começos de mês e fim de mês anteriores.

Qual seria a alternativa que poderia estar utilizando para pegar o valor de cada mês anterior e inserir dentro de um `array`?

Comment: vc quer apenas uma lista com com todos os meses do ano de janeiro até o mês atual? quer nome por extenso em português?

Comment: isso, necessariamente sim. Não sei se seria algo gigante para fazer isso.

Comment: Você tem como exemplificar esse `array` [editando a sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/397676/edit)?

Comment: Pronto, acabo de editar, a principio a dúvida é como saber todos os meses anteriores e inserir em um array, para ser trocado com o $comecoMes e $fimDoMes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução:

```
$quantitativo = [];

// Com essa expressão no for é possível gerar datas do mês atual até o inicio do ano
foreach(range(0, date('m') -1) as $i) {
    $data = Carbon::today()->subMonths($i);

    $inicio = $data->startOfMonth();
    $fim    = $data->endOfMonth();

    $qtde = Produto::where(['teste'=>$teste])
             ->whereBetween('updated_at',[$inicio, $fim])
             ->count(); // Repare que estou usando o count do query builder e não da collection como você estava usando

     $quantitativo[] = [
         'data' => $inicio,
         'total' => $qtde
     ];
}
```

Como especificado na pergunta a solução é isso ou perto disso, embora uma solução melhor seria gerar o quantitativo tudo em uma unica query, por que deste jeito no pior cenário executará 12 querys

Comment: Ótimo algorítimo, me deu uma grande base de como realizar. A principio estava procurando algo  simples assim mesmo. Agradecido

Answer (score 1):

Aproveitando seu código levando em consideração que seja um tipo date no seu where eu te informo o seguinte código

```
$datas = [
       //Caso precise das horas então só passar no formart H-i-s
       Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d'),
      Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d')
        ];

$quantidadeMesPassado = Produto::where(['teste'=>$teste])
            //Caso for dateTime e precise usar somente datas no between passa um DB::raw("date_format(updated_at, '%Y-%m-%d')") dentro do whereBetween que ira fazer validações somente por data, mas irá funcionar de boa.
             ->whereBetween('updated_at',$datas)
             ->get()
             ->count();
```

Qualquer dúvida manda um comentário aqui se eu puder ajudar, será uma satisfação.

Comment: No algoritimo apresentado por outra resposta ajudou a ter uma base, porém essa resposta ajudou a corrigir um outro erro que dava. De colocar o ->format('Y-m-d') nas datas do Carbon. Muito obrigado pela a ajuda.

Comment: Lembrando que você pode trocar o Now() por create($data) e pegar inicio do mês e fim